# Set local stratum 0 NTP server without internet

Tags: time, esp32

Currently, I'm doing a running track timing gate project to measure an accurate acceleration (a runner for example). The idea is when the runner triggers the first gate (start gate), the system will signals all other ESP32 to start the timing, and as the runner triggers other gates, the system will save each of their time. The expected precision is up to 10 ms.

[image: Example System]

I've managed to set up an NTP client with an NTP Server pool.ntp.org

```c
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval timeinfo;
volatile boolean flag = 0;
unsigned long prevTime = 0;
const char* ssid     = "********";
const char* password = "********";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Start_WiFi(ssid, password);
  configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org");
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(27), printLocalTime, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  //unsigned long int currTime;
  //currTime = millis();
  //if (currTime - prevTime >= 1000){
    //prevTime = currTime;
    if (timeinfo.tv_sec != 0 && not(flag)){
      Serial.printf("%ld.%06ld\n", timeinfo.tv_sec, timeinfo.tv_usec);
      flag = 1;
    }  
  //}
}

void printLocalTime() {
  gettimeofday(&timeinfo, 0);
}

int Start_WiFi(const char* ssid, const char* password) {
  int connAttempts = 0;
  Serial.println("\r\nConnecting to: " + String(ssid));
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    if (connAttempts > 20) return -5;
    connAttempts++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

However as I won't be having an internet connection I think that I need a different approach, I'm thinking of using a single ESP32 to behave like a stratum 0 NTP server or using Android phone as a stratum 0-like NTP server, which will be connected via a portable router. The other ESP32 will behave like a stratum 1 NTP server. I've read a solution to setup an NTP server using GPS, however actual current time is not necessary for this problem in my opinion.

Is this a good way to approach this problem? If yes, how do I setup a local stratum 0 NTP server?

Comment: why do you need an NTP server to time a race?

Comment: @jsotola I'm thinking to synchronizing 6 ESP32 to start their timer on a precision around 10 ms. Using NTP server is one solution that I can think of.

Comment: well, there is https://github.com/DennisSc/PPS-ntp-server

Comment: but you need only synchronize millis, not time and date.

Comment: I don't think you need to synch all the devices. Just have them send a packet as soon as the runner goes through the gate. The the single receiver-node will do the time measurements, based on the (local) times of the incoming packets. I don't think wifi jitter is more than 10ms, but you'd have to do some tests for that.

Comment: @Gerben, that sounds like an answer to the problem .... the OP's question is an X-Y question ...... the OP's system already has WiFi jitter ...... perhaps an initial handshake with one or more of  the sensor modules could be used to determine lag in the signal

Comment: @jsotola lag shouldn't matter. It's jitter that's potentially problematic. It is however possible to send [raw packets though the ESP](https://github.com/cnlohr/esp8266rawpackets), (not adhering to the wifi specification). As far a I can see, that would eliminate all possible jitter.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will try to implement the single receiver-node with raw packets.